# DataTable.DefaultView not updated after adding new rows to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF. I have a DataTable that is displayed in a DataGrid (which is databound to .DefaultView). A separate thread adds new rows to the DataTable, but these rows are not displayed in the DataGrid.

I guess I am doing something wrong. Could someone of you enlight me on how to display a DataTable in a DataGrid, while adding new rows programmatically?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh your grid after adding new rows.

```
//when dataTable changes
datagrid.Items.Refresh()
```